# Why composer does not tell us the EXACT reason of non-compliance with PSR-4?

Tags: php, composer-php

When we run `composer update/install/dumpautoload` commands, we sometimes see yellow boxes that basically tell us:

> Class X localted in Y does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

It becomes extremely time-consuming to find out **why** my class and my path is not compliant.

I know [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) has a couple of rules. But of course `composer` knows **EXACTLY** why my class and my path are not compliant.

Then why it doesn't give me that information to reduce the time and cost and energy of debugging the issue?

For example, `composer` might say:

> The casing of namespace in class X does not match the casing of the path Y.

or:

> Namespace of class X has more segments than its path Y.

Is there a reason for this vague general error message? Or is it because PHP community has not thought about it?

Comment: Why not open a feature request on Composer's issue tracker about this? Why not even fix that and send a pull request to the maintainers if you propose a better structure?

Answer (score 2):

The error is printed on `ClassMapGenerator::filterByNamespace()`. [Here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/a82607fb29064a80c77bac11ee24afab61078a78/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php#L198), specifically.

The only check that's made is that the expected path for a class does not match the actual path, and the warning is given accordingly. It's a simple equality check, composer does not know "exactly" why the class and path are not compliant, because it's not worth for composer to know that.

Generally having a proper PSR4 compliant file path is very easy, and checking why one does not match it's easy as well; not something I would ever describe as *"extremely time-consuming"*.

However, if you believe you can do better, I'm sure the project would accept a pull-request with this functionality as long as the quality was good enough and it followed the project conventions.